# Relationship with foreign keys in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

I am translating a recursive relationship in a schema to sql and i am trying to reference two columns in a table to one column in another table
the Schema is as following :

```
Table: Request
(
   mem_id1,
   mem id2,
   approved
)
```

desired foreign keys:

```
request.mem_id1 will reference member.mem_id  
request.mem_id2 will reference member.mem_id
```

I have tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
mem_id INTEGER,
f_name VARCHAR(10),
l_name VARCHAR(10),
address VARCHAR(40),
name VARCHAR(20),
domain VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY(mem_id)
)

CREATE TABLE member_phone (
mem_id INTEGER,
phone_no INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (mem_id,phone_no),
FOREIGN KEY (mem_id) REFERENCES members (mem_id)
)

CREATE TABLE request (
mem_id1 INTEGER,
mem_id2 INTEGER,
approved BIT(1),
PRIMARY KEY (mem_id1,mem_id2),
FOREIGN KEY (mem_id1,mem_id2) REFERENCES members (mem_id)
)
```

Comment: Ok. And what's the question? I don't see anything remotely related to recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want two separate foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE request (
mem_id1 INTEGER,
mem_id2 INTEGER,
approved BIT(1),
PRIMARY KEY (mem_id1, mem_id2),
FOREIGN KEY (mem_id1) REFERENCES members (mem_id),
FOREIGN KEY (mem_id2) REFERENCES members (mem_id)
)
```

Comment: oh i tried that before but i didn't figure that i forgot the ',',sorry for asking stupid questions tho,i'll mark your answer thank you

Comment: You do not have to feel stupid for asking questions, it's what the site is for.  I'm glad I was able to help.